# Implementing a simple linked list in C without malloc

Tags: c

All the implementations I have seen online use pointer to declare nodes and then will use malloc to create space for them like this:

```
struct Node  
{ 
  int data; 
  struct Node *next; 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
  struct Node* head = NULL; 
  struct Node* second = NULL; 
  struct Node* third = NULL; 

  head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  
  second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
  third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
...
```

But I can also create the same without pointers and malloc like this:

```
struct node {
   int  id;
   struct node* next;
};

struct node head = {0, NULL};
struct node one = {1, NULL};
struct node two = {2, NULL};
struct node tail = {3, NULL};

int main(){
   head.next = &one;
   one.next = &two;
   two.next = &tail;
...
```

My question is, why the 1st method is mostly the one used, why do we need to declare each node as pointer and why do we need malloc?
(Just to point out I know why `struct Node *next;` is declared as pointer int the struct declaration).

Comment: We usually don't use global variables nor write all the code in `main`, that's why the first version is more used.

Comment: That, and you rarely know exactly how long your linked list will need to be when it's created. If you do, there's not much point in resizable structures anyway.

Comment: You can't add any additional nodes to your version.  If you've created one, two, three and while your program runs the user asks for _4_ nodes you're in trouble.  The code to change links (for example to sort the nodes) is also very painful with your approach.

Comment: Also, it has been demonstrated that such linked lists are usually a bad idea anyway. An array outperforms here, even if you need to delete in middle.

Answer (score 3):

You should do this with local variables, not global ones, but the general idea would be the same. You should also steer towards having arrays and not heaps of otherwise unrelated variables:

```
struct node {
   int  id;
   struct node* next;
};

int main(){
  struct node nodes[4];

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    nodes[i].id = (3 - i);

    if (i != 0) {
      nodes[i].next = &nodes[i-1];
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Where something like that assembles them in reverse order for convenience, but they're all grouped together in terms of memory initially.

`malloc` is used because you often don't know how many you're going to have, or they get added and removed unpredictably. A general-purpose solution would allocate them as necessary. A specialized implementation might allocate them as a single block, but that's highly situational.

Here the lifespan of `nodes` is within that function alone, so as soon as that function ends the data goes away. In other words:

```
struct node* allocateNodes() {
  struct node nodes[10];

  return &nodes; // Returns a pointer to an out-of-scope variable, undefined behaviour
}
```

That won't work. You need a longer lived allocation which is precisely what `malloc` provides:

```
struct node* allocateNodes() {
  struct node *nodes = calloc(10, sizeof(struct node));

  return nodes; // Returns a pointer to an allocated structure, which is fine
}
```

The problem is if you `malloc` you are responsible for calling `free` to release the memory, so it becomes more work.

You'll see both styles used in code depending on the required lifespan of the variables in question.

Answer (score 3):

If you know ahead of time exactly how many items will be in your list, then you're probably better off using an array rather than a list. The whole point of a linked list is to be able to grow to an unknown size at runtime, and that requires dynamic memory allocation (i.e., malloc).

Comment: Corner case: You could dynamically create a list of statically allocated objects at program startup time. You could link a number of drivers (names and number unknown at compile time) as object files to your executable. Each driver object file contains one statically allocated `static struct driver` object and registers that from an `__attribute__(( constructor ))` function. The registering will set up the `next` pointer for the linked list. Then `main()` will see runtime generated (once only, on program startup) list of drivers to iterate over. For `main()`, that list is static.

Comment: linked lists also have other useful properties that arrays do not, such as ease of insertion or deletion of an item.